# Как привести список со словарями к списку строк "ключ - значение"?

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть список, имеющий вид:

```
[{ 'artist': 'Название исполнителя', 'title': 'Название трека' } , { 'artist': 'Название исполнителя 2', 'title': 'Название трека 2' } , { 'artist': 'Название исполнителя 3', 'title': 'Название трека 3'}]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как привести его к виду:

```
["Название исполнителя - Название трека", "Название исполнителя 2 - Название трека 2", "Название исполнителя 3 - Название трека 3"]
```

Добавив символы " - " между значениями бывших ключей.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [ { 'artist': 'Название исполнителя', 'title': 'Название трека' } , { 'artist': 'Название исполнителя 2', 'title': 'Название трека 2' } , { 'artist': 'Название исполнителя 3', 'title': 'Название трека 3'}]
res = ["{} - {}".format(x['artist'], x['title']) for x in a]                                                                                                                                               
print(res)
```

получите:

```
['Название исполнителя - Название трека', 'Название исполнителя 2 - Название трека 2', 'Название исполнителя 3 - Название трека 3']
```